# how to implement an ordered but not sorted priorityqueue in java?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I follow the example from [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example.html) to create a `PriorityQueue`. it worked great and I was able to prioritize my objects. but the question I have is in my understanding, `Queue` is FIFO. so lets say if I create a `PriorityQueue` and sort it by priority. I first add an object to the queue with priority=Low and value=c. then I add another object to my `PriorityQueue` with priority set to High and value set to b. finally I want to add another object to `PriorityQueue` with high priority also but value=a. then I do `poll()` to print out these three objects I get

```
priority: High, value: a
priority: High, value: b
priority: Low, value: c
```

the priority is sorted correctly, but I want the two objects with the same priority follow the FIFO rule. since b is added first before a, the expected result should be

```
priority: High, value: b
priority: High, value: a
priority: Low, value: c
```

is this doable? I have my comparator as follow

```
private static Comparator<Request> comparator = new Comparator<Request>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Request r1, Request r2) {
        return (int) (r1.priority - r2.priority);
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. From the [PriorityQueue docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. **If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.** *(emphasis added)*

What you could do is assign each `Request` a unique, incrementing ID, and then use that in your comparator to break the tie between equally-prioritized instances.

Comment: get it! thanks for the quick help